# Can I add an image to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, images

> [image]

In the above image, the user @timbillstrom is telling us how to add an image... Can someone elaborate on where exactly do you put the image (assuming it's a Name.png file on your laptop)?

My basis for this question is, can I add an image in a comment or only in a question or answer?

Comment: No, comments are for text only and are mainly for asking for clarification of the question or answer and are not considered a permanent part of a question or answer. I can't see how an image will assist in this purpose, which begs the question -- why would you want to display one in a comment?

Comment: See [Editing Help on comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for what you can do with comments.

Comment: Example comment image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4hrJ.png

Comment: A word of advice: don't (try to) use the site as you please, use the site as intended. That means that you need to not ignore signals. The fact that you don't see any means of putting an image in a comment and that you don't see any images in comments when looking at existing questions are pretty big signals that you probably shouldn't do that. When you realise that, that implies you maybe don't fully understand what comments are for. Which means you should go find that out. Give yourself reasons to go look for that information, it makes Stack Overflow so much less confusing.

Comment: (emojis are images: ) (Testing the new system font with emojis)

Comment: @0-1 Emoji are characters, and part of the Unicode standard. *Not* allowing them to be used would be the exceptional case. That's very different from an arbitrary image.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do something like this would be to:

1. In the Answer (or Question) interface, add a picture as if you were going to post an answer. The textarea will then contain something like this:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4hrJ.png
```

2. Take the link from the bottom, and paste it into your comment, without posting a new question or answer. Discard the new question or answer draft that was created when you uploaded the image.

The image won't be embedded as an actual image, of course - comments can contain only text - but other users will be able to click on it to get to the image.

See my comment on your question for an example.

> where exactly do you put the image (assuming its a Name.png file on your laptop)

Press the Image icon at the top of the editor:

[image]

and then you'll be able to either drag and drop the image in, or browse to the image file on your filesystem, or paste in a link to an image. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for details.

I've done this a few times - but if you're at the point where you need to communicate something with an image, remember that comments aren't meant for extended discussion.

Comment: Re: press the icon - or do a Ctrl (cmd) + G as a shortcut (maybe worth mentioning for future readers)